# How to get value in a td by clicking its button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam trying to get the value in a td while clicking a button in it. 
I used the code below and get only blank value.

So i tried to change the css to see whether it selectes the specific td. Then
    `$(this).parents('tr td:nth-child(8)').css('color','red');` 
didnt work but

```
$(this).parents('tr').css('color','red');
```

worked and made that row data in all td in red color. why this ?

Comment: your code html please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the first code example is that the `td:nth-child(8)` is not the parent of the element referenced in `this`, the `tr` is.

To solve this you need to use separate calls to `parents()` and `find()`, like this:

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(8)').css('color','red');
```

Also note that assuming that you only want to find the immediate `tr` parent element, you can replace `parents()` with `closest()` for slightly improved performance.

Comment: that was a life saver. and very little and short solution. It gives proper understanding of targeting elements.

Comment: @Bineesh if it solved your problem, please mark this as  the answer.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL server says to wait some minutes to mark it answered.

Comment: @Bineesh Thanks, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.text()` to get the text inside the clicked on TD.

```js
$('td').click(function(){
   var num = $(this).text();
   alert(num);
});
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{padding:5px;border:1px solid #ccc;}
.here{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td class="here">8675309</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

If you also have a button inside the TD that you want to click on, then get the desired text in relation to the button location:

```js
$('#btnMyDiv').click(function(){
   var num = $(this).closest('td').find('div').text();
   alert(num);
});
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{padding:5px;border:1px solid #ccc;}
.here{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td class="here">
    <div id="myDiv">555-1212</div>
    <button id="btnMyDiv">Click Me</button>
    </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

And this is how you can get the data from a different TD:

```js
$('#btnMyDiv').click(function(){
   var num = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text();
   alert(num);
});
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{padding:5px;border:1px solid #ccc;}
.here{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell</td><td>YabaDabaDoo</td><td class="here">
    <div id="myDiv">555-1212</div>
    <button id="btnMyDiv">Click Me</button>
    </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i need the data from other specific td. not the closest or the the cell clicked.

Comment: How can you identify that td?

Comment: that is what i was seeking and pls see Rory McCrossan answer to it.

Comment: Okay (I also answered it above)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't notice Rory's answer -- he's right, of course.